# Unexpected type for header x-ms-meta-ownerType

Tags: azure-blob-storage

While trying to set metadata for file upload in Azure Blob Storage,Getting this error

```
{
    "isSuccess": false,
    "statusCode": 500,
    "statusMessage": "Unexpected type for header x-ms-meta-ownerType: ",
    "body": null
}
```

**This is code snippet :**

```
public async Task PutBlobAsync(BlobContainerClient containerClient, Stream stream, string blobId, IDictionary<string, string> metaData, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobId);
            BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeader = new()
            {
                ContentType = FileHelper.GetContentType(FileHelper.GetExtension(blobId))
            };
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, new BlobUploadOptions
            {
                HttpHeaders = blobHttpHeader
            }, ct);
            // Set the blob's metadata.
            await blobClient.SetMetadataAsync(metaData);
        }
```

this is funcation for setting meta data

```
 public IDictionary<string, string> SetMetaData(FileUploadRequest request)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> metaData = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "ownerType", request.OwnerType },
                { "documentType", request.DocumentType },
                { "container", request.Container }
            };
            return metaData;
        }
```

While this function was working fine before, the addition of the cancellation token may have introduced an issue. This is because it was the last change made to the code.

I read the Azure documentation but didn't find anything related to my issue. Maybe I didn't understand it fully
[Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata?tabs=azure-ad)

Comment: I got the solution by my self. I realized that I had passed null as the value for ownerType